# Error in local-hosting github simple html project

Tags: php, angularjs, html, file-manager

I am using Wampp server and trying to use [this GITHUB project](https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager)

I downloded the zip and simply accessing it through localhost but the project is not functioning it says `Bridge response error, please check the docs` Anyone help

Comment: Well... have you tried checking the docs?

Comment: yeah , but i am not friendly with bower can you explain please